# Image resize issue

Tags: product, product-images, media-images, magento2.4.0, gd2

I am uploading below image for the product via backend. [image]

But it changes to below image [image]

It is clearly visible that it changes the color. I have tried using ImageMagik also.  I have even tried this with vanila Magento too. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your original file color profile ? Gd or imagemagick can override color profile and this difference can happen.

Comment: what should I tell designer about this issue?

Comment: İf your open both files on photoshop, (original and converted) you can see color profile and i believe you should convert a global color profile such as adobe sRGB before uploading to website.